# Quoting characters in JavaScript attribute names?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Let's say you have some JavaScript code that is receiving an object that has an '@' symbol as the first character of the attribute name. How can you access that attribute?

Example:

```
    var data = { 
        id: 1, 
        msg: "blah blah blah", 
        '@timestamp': "2023-03-28T23:08:03Z" 
    };
```

I know `data.id` and `data.msg` work, but how can I access the `data.@timestamp` attribute?

I have tried `data.@timestamp`, and I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token". I have also tried `data.'@timestamp'` and that didn't work, as well as `data.\@timestamp`, and various other permutations attempting to somehow quote the `@` symbol.

Is this even possible?

*(Note: Renaming the attribute to remove the '@' symbol is not easily possible, because I will be receiving this data from a back-end API.)*

Comment: `data["@timestamp"]`

Comment: I also discovered that Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(data, '@timestamp').value works, although it's much less readable.